# ERC721 NFT not showing in opensea (related to the metadata)

Tags: json, solidity, ipfs

I was creating the DApp and succeeded to mint NFT in Rinkeby using IPFS (pinata) & Nethereum (C#).

Now, I can get TokenURI using tokenURI function in ERC721URIStorage.sol, like `ipfs://QmRH9pTTADs3BCqMLqXEAMP83FoaeMD8CUkNgtxZ5HKTLq`.

Below is link of the metadata about same NFT.
(https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmRH9pTTADs3BCqMLqXEAMP83FoaeMD8CUkNgtxZ5HKTLq)

But, in opensea testnet, I can't see the information about my NFT. (I can see my NFT, but there is no image, name, description, and so on..)

To solve this problem, I checked if my contract is valid or not in https://testnets-api.opensea.io/asset/0x1770A249C9743F1493C55fE505BC17beAB772cD5/4/validate/. There is some error : "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'", but I don't know what it is..

Even though I can get TokenURI, why doesn't opensea? In this docs (https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards), they say if I want to use IPFS to host my metadata, URL should be in the format ipfs:// (like `ipfs://QmRH9pTTADs3BCqMLqXEAMP83FoaeMD8CUkNgtxZ5HKTLq`.) I followed that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I find that my json in ipfs is not a json, because it is surrounded with "".

It means that opensea will fail to get something from my metadata because it is string.

I used another sample metadata (https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeibnsoufr2renqzsh347nrx54wcubt5lgkeivez63xvivplfwhtpym/metadata.json) which is not mine, and it worked very well!

Therefore, I have to fix the code for uploading metadata to ipfs.

I have not solved the problem completely, but I find the cause, so I will quit this question. After I solve this problem, I will post again.

Comment: The reason why my metadata is string (not json) is duplicated-escaping. I upload my metadata using unity & pinata api. I use wwwform and unitywebrequest to post my json to "pinJSONToIPFS". Because I add json to wwwform using AddField("fieldName", "jsonString"), applying escaping is done twice, and that makes metadata string. (And there are '\' letters in metadata, because of the same reason) So I delete using AddField to add json, and just upload single json to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

just put this in smart contract tada its solved

````
function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        _requireMinted(tokenId);

        string memory baseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, Strings.toString(tokenId),".json")) : "";
    }```
````